# How to map (transform) a map to a new map with modified keys and values

Tags: sass, dart-sass

Given following map:

```
$colors: (
  "primary": "#0d6efd",
  "secondary": "#6c757d",
   ...
)
```

how do I create new map where key will be `#{$key}-light` and value e.g result of `ligthen($value, 20%)`:

expected result:

```
$colors-light: (
  "primary-light": ...,
  "secondary-light": ...
)
```

in javascript it would be something like:

```
const colors-light = new Map(
  [...colors.entries()].map(i => [
     `${i[0]}-light`, //key
      lighten(i[1], 0.2) //value
  ])
);
```

in C# it would be:

```
colors.ToDictionary(
   item => $"{item.Key}-light", 
   item => Lighten(item.Value, 0.2)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, there is no way to do it without a loop:

```
$color-light: ();

@each $colorName, $colorValue in $colors {
    $color-light: map.set($color-light, #{$colorName}-light, ligthen($colorValue, 20%));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a [@each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) loop and [map-merge](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#merge):

```
$colors: (
  "primary": "#0d6efd",
  "secondary": "#6c757d",
  ...
);

$color-light: ();

@each $colorName, $colorValue in $colors {
    $color-light: map-merge($color-light, (
        #{$colorName}-light: ligthen($colorValue, 20%)
    ));
}
```

Comment: if it must be done using loop, wouldn't be a map.set a better option?

Comment: From what I read in the doc, `map.set` will returns a map with a single value changed. You need to change multiple values and key names so it can't work here.

Comment: Did it solve your problem @Liero ?

Comment: I did it using map.set in a `each-in` loop, which is more suitable than a map-merge with single single key in a loop.

Comment: @Liero maybe you could post it as an answer then? It may help other people. :)